# Seeding sqlite db from EF6 with new data

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-6, seeding

I'm trying migrations with https://github.com/bubibubi/sqliteef6migrations library. It's working OK with his main example:

```
internal sealed class ContextMigrationConfiguration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<Context>
    {
        public ContextMigrationConfiguration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
            AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
            SetSqlGenerator("System.Data.SQLite", new SQLiteMigrationSqlGenerator());
        }
    }
```

But when I try to do this it fails:

```
public sealed class ContextMigrationConfiguration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<UnitOfWork>
    {
        private readonly bool _pendingMigrations;

        public ContextMigrationConfiguration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
            AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
            SetSqlGenerator("System.Data.SQLite", new SQLiteMigrationSqlGenerator());

            var migrator = new DbMigrator(this);
            _pendingMigrations = migrator.GetPendingMigrations().Any();

            if (_pendingMigrations)
            {
                migrator.Update();
                Seed(new UnitOfWork());
            }
        }

        protected sealed override void Seed(UnitOfWork context) 
        {
            // Initialization
        }
   }
```

`_pendingMigrations = migrator.GetPendingMigrations().Any();` Fails with

> System.ObjectDisposedException on `.GetPendingMigrations()`
>
> | ObjectName | "SQLiteConnection"   | Source | "System.Data.SQLite"
>
> | StackTrace | "   en
>   System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection.CheckDisposed()\r\n   en
>   System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection.get_State()\r\n   en
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.RepositoryBase.CreateConnection()\r\n   en
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.History.HistoryRepository.QueryExists(String
>   contextKey)\r\n   en
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.History.HistoryRepository.Exists(String
>   contextKey)\r\n   en
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.History.HistoryRepository.GetPendingMigrations(IEnumerable`1
>   localMigrations)\r\n   en
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.GetPendingMigrations()\r\n
>   en QApps.DataLayer.Context.ContextMigrationConfiguration..ctor() en
>   D:\Projects\...\Context\UnitOfWork.cs:línea 91"

I'm trying to init the db with some test data, but if I use Seed directly it set the data every time the app is launched, so I'm trying to Seed only after an update.

One thing I don't have migrations enabled yet, I just use it to create the db and populate it with some test data.

Maybe the problen is not related to the library but another part of the code. Any help will be apreciated.